# Dynamically changing the view with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do a simple task.

1. I have a button on a page
2. I click the button and it shows a label and an HTML select drop-down list.
3. Whenever I change drop-down list value, the label should change.

The code is below. Whenever I run it, it the label just changes once and the options tab never changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  showButton();
});

function showButton() {

   //draw button
    var $button = '<button type="button" id= "button">Button</button>';
    $('.div1').after(button);

    //add event listener on click
     document.getElementById("thebutton").addEventListener("click",showLabel());
}

function showLabel() {
   var label = "one";
   var option = document.getElementById("options").value;

   if(option == "one") {
        label = "one";
   }
   if(option == "two") {
        label = "two";
   }
   if(option == "two") {
        label = "three";
   }

   var selectOptions = '<div align ="right"><select id="options"><option value="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option><option value="three">three</option></select></div>';

   document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = selectOptions+ label;

   document.getElementById("options").addEventListener("change", function(){
        console.log('changed option');
        showLabel();
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.div1').append('<button type="button" onclick="javascript:showLabel()" id="button">Button</button>');
    $('.container').append('<div><select id="options"><option value="1">one</option><option value="2">two</option><option value="3">three</option></select></div>');
});

function showLabel() {
    var option = document.getElementById("options").value;

    if (option == 1) {
        labelVal = 'one';
    } else if (option == 2) {
        labelVal = 'two';
    } else if (option == 3) {
        labelVal = 'three';
    }

    if (document.getElementById('label') != null) {
        $('#label').val(labelVal);
    } else {
        $('.container').append('<input type="text" id="label" value="' + labelVal + '">');
    }
}
</script>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: doesn't answer question

Comment: Edited the answer. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.